# Notify Firebase app server of messages between devices

Tags: rest, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is it possible to configure Firebase app server to receive notification when there are messages exchanged between two other devices over Firebase Cloud Messaging?

So for instance I want to save these messages via my app server to the database. Currently I do it with additional REST request when I receive message on target phone.

However I want to avoid two jobs on target devices(listening/receiving the message and sending a request to save it) I'm thinking there must be an option where User sends a message from their phone and it not only arrives at target device but also notifies server?

Comment: Check this one:https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Comment: yeah, thats what I'm using ,but can't find info on how to listen for messages on app server as well

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to register your own observer that hooks in to Firebase Cloud Messaging's message sending mechanism.

There is also no capability to send messages directly from one device to another. There is always a piece of code that you deploy to a trusted environment (e.g. an app server of [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions)) involved in sending so-called downstream messages to devices.

Two approaches that may accomplish the same need are:

1. [Implement an XMPP server](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#implementing-the-xmpp-connection-server-protocol) that sits between the devices sending messages and the FCM server that delivers messages to devices
2. Implement an intermediate service where the devices send the message, which then in turn calls FCM. This is a more generic approach of the previous one and is described in [this blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html) and in this [use-case in the Cloud Functions for Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens).